# Error in overriding image property of ImageView

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiimage, abstract-class

I am trying to override getter of ImageView to return placeholder image if imageView not settled, But I have error and I can not do it.

Why this happens and how can I solve this problem?

My code

```
 @implementation OvalImageView
- (UIImage *)image
{
  return _image? _image : [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-big-placeholder"];
}
```

> Error:  Use of undeclared identifier '_image'

Comment: solved with [super image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved

```
- (UIImage *)image
{
return [super image]? [super image] : [UIImage imageNamed:@"avatar-big-placeholder"];
}
```

I did it this way because I need to load imageView with image placeholder if there is no users photo in that imageView. Then user add photo the placeholders done. Simple and effective for me

Comment: Might help to add why you did it this way for others who come upon this question.